# Почему нет мобильной адаптации на web-странице?

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка

начал разрабатывать адаптивный макет с мобильной версии (320px по-умолчанию), далее добавил пару media-выражений (таблет и десктоп), однако при изменении размера окна, мобильная версия игнорируется, скажите, что напутал т.к. это мой первый адаптивный макет.

репозиторий: https://github.com/iZemil/pink
домен: https://izemil.github.io/pink/

Comment: Какие именно выражения вы имеете ввиду? что именно игнорируется? покажите кусок кода. Какой результат вы желаете получить?

Comment: @kizoso, есть три версии сайта: от 320px, от 768px, от 1200px. Если посмотреть хроме в режиме просмотра кода, то при изменение размера окна можно увидеть, что сайт изменяет свой внешний вид при 768 и 1200, а 320 нет никакой реакции. Код выше

Comment: Хочу увидеть изменение лого сайта, загружены 3 версии, 2 из них можно увидеть, мобильную нет

Comment: на 1200 код вижу, на 768 код вижу, на 320 не вижу

Comment: @kizoso, ведь 320 по-умолчанию, то есть медиа выражения должны игнорироваться, если ширина вьюпорта меньше 768. Чего может не хватать?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @kizoso, по вашему не хватает дополнительного медия выражения? или что вы бы предложили сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем html я не обнаружил:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: а не подскажите как сделать плавные переходы от разных версий, чтобы не рублено так было 320 > 768 > 1200?

Comment: @Эмиль Задавайте отдельный вопрос. А этот можете пометить как решенный. Но про "плавные переходы" я не понял. Можете указать какой-то пример, как вы хотите чтобы реализовывался переход между точками?

Comment: например если сайт отобразить на устройстве в 480px его рабочая область будет 320px, то есть он не растягивается на все 480px, как-то можно растяжку применить??

Comment: Ну изменять стили нужно. Скорее всего, в стилях указана ширина контейнера в 320px.